# How to preserve line breaks in <code> block?

Tags: css

I have some code samples which I want to publish in an HTML document. I'm wrapping them with `<code>`, tags but I'd like them to be styled such that line breaks are preserved. I can do this by also enclosing them with `<pre>` tags, but I'd prefer to use CSS.

I've tried the following in IE7 (which according to [this reference](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html) should work), but with no joy (line breaks are stripped):

```
code {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: If the line breaks are meaningful, then they are "content," not "style," and should be coded with &lt;pre&gt; tags. Would it change the meaning of your page if a user stylesheet reset your code to a different style?

Comment: The meaning would not be changed in that case (it's C code so line breaks are not meaningful to the parser).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check your doctype is valid and on the first line. Maybe it's slipping into quirks mode?

Answer (score 21):

Are you sure you're not doing something wrong? This code works for me on IE7:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  code { white-space: pre; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <code>
      function() {
          alert('yay');
      }
  </code>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it worked for me! I also found `pre-wrap` which wraps both for line breaks in the text as well as when needed: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp --- "Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks"