# How to avoid line breaks inside `->` operator in `<code>` blocks?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I have a [large HTML document](http://cplusplus.github.io/fundamentals-ts/main.html) containing C++ inline `<code>` sequences like `foo->bar`. Because hyphens are often used to induce line breaks, this sometimes results in output like:

> blah blah `foo-`
>   `>bar` blah blah

which is undesirable.

- Replacing the `-` (U+002D) with a `‑` (U+2011; non-breaking hyphen) isn't acceptable because it breaks searching for `->` in common browsers.
- Styling `<code>` elements with `white-space:nowrap` is undesirable because some inline code segments are long enough that they really should wrap.
- Manually styling each `->` operator with `<span style="white-space:nowrap">` (or `<nobr>`) is unacceptable because of the editorial burden, but it's possible to write a script to do this.

Is there a declarative way to specify that inside `->` isn't a good place to break a line?

(This question is not actually a duplicate of [How can I use CSS to preserve line breaks in an HTML <code> block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011641/how-can-i-use-css-to-preserve-line-breaks-in-an-html-code-block): this question asks how to *avoid* line breaks, while that question asks how to *create* them.)

Comment: is searching for `->` really serious? I've never searched for such a thing, just keywords only.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a solution that satisfies all your criteria. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691569/no-line-break-after-a-hyphen

Comment: @King King: I've several times had to search my own code for `foo->bar`. I don't think he's only referring to searching for the `->` operator alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No css declarative way by now. As far as I know there is no defined format for dictionaries to be used with hyphenate-resource (or @hyphenate-resource) or wide support for it, even using vendor specific dictionaries...

Use spans and script it as you pointed: *but it's possible to write a script to do this*

It's not a perfect solution, but it satisfies all your criteria and it is crossbrowser

Comment: Kinda sucks, but it's good to get some confirmation that I'm not missing anything.

Comment: Yes, I know. :D The worst is that it was removed (http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-text-20110412/ vs http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-text-20110901) and the other hyphenate-... properties that could give some kind of option was deferred to level 4 (http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-text-20120119/)