# How do I display the code as plain text

Tags: javascript

this is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <p id="x"></p>
        <p id="y"></p>
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
        <script src="jquery/jquery1.12.js"></script>
        <script>
            var txt = '<!DOCTYPE html>\
                       <html>\
                       <head>\ 
                       </head>\
                       <body>\
                       <script>\
                       alert("ok");\
                       </script>\
                       </body>\
                       </html>';

           $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#btn").click(function(){
                   $("#x").text(txt);
               })
           })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I display the code as plain text.i want each line variable x go to new line for example :

output as :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
up to the end
```

any help,tankyou.

Answer (score 1):

In you `#x` element, you should use a `pre` element instead of `p`.

Plus you should move it from the `head` to the `body`

Check out this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/qicabanoze/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It's ES6 template literal

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the code from executing and not displaying you'll need to convert the text to character entities. **> becomes &gt**, **< becomes &lt**, etc.

You can also use the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags to display formatted code.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the symbols '<' '>' to `&lt;` and `&gt;`
and it will work.

You can use `<code>` or `<pre>`, but for the last one you will need to change the text style (default font).

Comment: Tankyou when use tag code,all tags are in one line i want each line be in new line.

Comment: Please check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011641/how-can-i-use-css-to-preserve-line-breaks-in-an-html-code-block